# JavaScript problem about calculation and concatenation

Tags: javascript, alert

Whenever am adding the calculation part at middle of ALERT,, its showing me unexpected output. I entered DOG AGE as 5yrs but its showing output as 1221 . Check first picture.
but when am entering the calculation part at the starting,, its showing me correct result. check second image.
why is so??

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Please, format your question properly - put code here with `code` snippet. Do not use images.

Comment: [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns the user input as a **string**. You need to `Number.pasrseInt(prompt(...))`.

Comment: Please refer to [ask] and how to post a [mcve]. [Images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are OK but isn't mandatory but code as a [mcve] is required 99% of the time.

Answer (score -1):

You are not adding brackets around the calculation. So, it is calculating only (dogage-2)*4 and appending 21 to the output. Below works

```js
alert("your dog age is :" + ((dogage-2)*4+21) +" yrs old in human age");
```